# Concatenating strings

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

I want to join a `vector<string>` into a single `string`, separated by spaces.  For example,

```
sample
string
for
this
example
```

should become `"sample string for this example"`.
What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> v;
...

std::stringstream ss;
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ss, " "));
std::string result = ss.str();
if (!result.empty()) {
    result.resize(result.length() - 1); // trim trailing space
}
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Comment: It's a shame about the need to trim the trailing space though.

Comment: It looks like that's one of the things that boost::join does for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833447/a-good-example-for-boostalgorithmjoin

Answer (score 4):

boost::join

Comment: Without a good example, boost::join is a world of pain.  The documentation assumes at least a litle familiarity with the Boost Range library.