# A good example for boost::algorithm::join

Tags: c++, string, boost, join

I recently wanted to use  [boost::algorithm::join](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.join_hpp) but I couldn't find any usage examples and I didn't want to invest a lot of time learning the Boost Range library just to use this one function.

Can anyone provide a good example of how to use join on a container of strings?  Thanks.

Comment: When looking for examples for boost library "foo", it is often a good idea to look at boost/libs/foo/examples and boost/libs/foo/test. In the present case, you could look at boost/libs/algorithm/string/test/join_test.cpp

Answer (score 246, accepted):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> list;
    list.push_back("Hello");
    list.push_back("World!");

    std::string joined = boost::algorithm::join(list, ", ");
    std::cout << joined << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Can it support custom types? For example, class `A` has a method `ToString` which returns a `string` value.Can I use `join` to join a `vector<A>` by calling `ToString` on each element?

Comment: @KenZhang: No, because this is a rather specialized implementation. The usual STL style is to use iterator pairs, and then you can use `boost::transform_iterator` to wrap the `.ToString` methods. But this `join` method takes a container instead of an iterator pair.

Answer (score 43):

```
std::vector<std::string> MyStrings;
MyStrings.push_back("Hello");
MyStrings.push_back("World");
std::string result = boost::algorithm::join(MyStrings, ",");

std::cout << result; // prints "Hello,World"
```

Comment: This answer shows less effort than the older one and provides no added value. Why is it still present here?

Comment: @arekolek because it was posted almost at the same time (~2 minutes diff)?