# C++ help - getline

Tags: c++, whitespace, getline

I've been doing C++ for two weeks now, i'm creating a very simple program which allows the user to input their name, and then it outputs there full name, here is the code;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string first ;
    string middle ;
    string last;

    cout << "What is your firstname?" << endl;
    getline(cin, first);
    cout << "Your firstname is ";
    first = first;
    cout << first << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "What is your middle name?" << endl;
    getline(cin, middle);
    cout << "Your middle name is ";
    middle = middle;
    cout << middle << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "What is your lastname?" << endl;
    getline(cin, last);
    cout << "Your lastname is ";
    last = last;
    cout << last << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Your full name is " <<  first + middle + last << endl;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that it won't output spaces in the last cout

```
cout << "Your full name is " <<  first + middle + last << endl;
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Well, you're not telling to print any spaces, why would it?

Comment: Is that what you want to do: `cout << "Your full name is " <<  first << " " << middle  << " " << last << endl;`

Comment: You're managing to print sentences already; think about it. A space is `" "`.

Comment: @Zane I had actually tried that, and it worked fine. The problem is that it looked untidy, is there a better way of doing it? Or is that the only way.

Comment: You can certainly use a 'joiner' of some kind that joins with a specified character. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1833499/721269) for the Boost way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your output line to

```
cout << "Your full name is " <<  first << " " << middle << " " << last << endl;
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what Zane suggested, but the OP said it looked untidy? I'm confused.

Comment: (Just to clarify, +1 as it's an appropriate answer given 2 weeks of C++ experience.)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not telling it to write spaces where I think you want them.

My guess is that you get spaces just fine in

```
"Your full name is "
```

Then you want spaces between you `first`, `middle` and `last` strings?
But you never add any spaces there.

The part that looks like

```
<<  first + middle + last <<
```

must be changed to include spaces

```
<<  first + " " + middle + " " + last <<
```

So you entire cout at the end should be

```
cout << "Your full name is " <<  first + " " + middle + " " + last << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string first ;
    string middle ;
    string last;

    cout << "What is your firstname?\n";
    getline(cin, first);
    cout << "Your firstname is " << first << "\n\n";

    cout << "What is your middle name?\n";
    getline(cin, middle);
    cout << "Your middle name is " << middle << "\n\n";

    cout << "What is your lastname?\n";
    getline(cin, last);
    cout << "Your lastname is " << last << "\n\n";

    cout << "Your full name is " <<  first +" "+ middle +" "+ last << "\n\n";

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```