# Can boost:algorithm::join() concat a container of floats?

Tags: c++, string, boost, stl, adapter

Boost join can be used to concatenate a container of strings optionally separated by a separator string as shown in this example: [A good example for boost::algorithm::join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833447/a-good-example-for-boostalgorithmjoin)

My STL skills are weak.  I'm wondering if there is any way to use the same function for a container of numbers (floats, doubles, ints)?  It just seems like there should some one or two-liner to adapt it for other types.

There is also stl's copy function with a good example found here:
[How to print out the contents of a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/c-printing-out-the-contents-of-a-vector)

But I don't like how it adds the separator string after every element. I'd like to just use boost.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sure, you can combine `boost::algorithm::join` and [`boost::adaptors::transformed`](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html) to convert the doubles to strings and then join them together.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>

int main()
{
    using boost::adaptors::transformed;
    using boost::algorithm::join;

    std::vector<double> v{1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};

    std::cout 
      << join( v | 
               transformed( static_cast<std::string(*)(double)>(std::to_string) ), 
               ", " );
}
```

Output:

> 1.100000, 2.200000, 3.300000, 4.400000

---

You can also use a lambda to avoid the ugly cast

```
join(v | transformed([](double d) { return std::to_string(d); }), ", ")
```

Comment: what does  '|' symbol mean? it is XOR, I know, but I don't understand how it can be used with "vector<int> | transformed([]...): ?? I tried to compile this with boost 1.47 and gcc 4.6.3 - I had a lot of errors...

Comment: @AlexandrDerkach It's not XOR, it's bitwise OR for builtins (`int`s and such). In this case, it's an overloaded operator, search for `operator|` [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp). You can read about the requirements for the first argument `SinglePassRange` [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/concepts/single_pass_range.html). stdlib containers like `vector` meet those requirements. The code above is applying the argument to `transform` to each element of the `vector`.

Comment: Oh, it is really interesting feature! I wasn't familiar with it. Going to read it.. thanks ( and sorry, it was a typo - a meant OR, of course :)

Answer (score 2):

> My STL skills are weak. I'm wondering if there is anyway to use the same function for a container of numbers (floats, doubles, ints)? It just seems like there should some one- or two-liner to adapt it for other types.

`std::accumulate` allows to do a fold over any (input) iterator range, using a binary function which can take different types for the "accumulator" and the next item. In your case: A function taking a `std::string` and a `double` (or whatever) that concatenates the given `std::string` with the result of `std::to_string` on the second parameter.

```
template<typename Container>
std::string contents_as_string(Container const & c,
                               std::string const & separator) {
  if (c.size() == 0) return "";
  auto fold_operation = [&separator] (std::string const & accum,
                                      auto const & item) {
    return accum + separator + std::to_string(item);};
  return std::accumulate(std::next(std::begin(c)), std::end(c),
                         std::to_string(*std::begin(c)), fold_operation);
}
```

As you can see, this is completely independent of the value type of the container. As long as you can pass it to `std::to_string` you're good.
Actually, above code is a slight variation of [the example presented for `std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

[Demo of above function](http://ideone.com/Jtio12):

```
int main() {
  std::vector<double> v(4);
  std::iota(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0.1);
  std::cout << contents_as_string(v, ", ") << std::endl;

  std::vector<int> w(5);
  std::iota(std::begin(w), std::end(w), 1);
  std::cout << contents_as_string(w, " x ") << " = "
    << std::accumulate(std::begin(w), std::end(w), 1, std::multiplies<int>{})
    << std::endl;
}
```

> 0.100000, 1.100000, 2.100000, 3.100000
>   1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5 = 120