# An effective way to concatenate multiple buffers

Tags: c++

I need to design an **efficient** and **readable** class with 2 main functions:

- `add_buffer(char* buffer)` - add a buffer.
- `char* read_all()` - get one big buffer that contains all the buffers that the user added until now (by order).

for example:

```
char first_buffer[] = {1,2,3};
char second_buffer[] = {4,5,6};

MyClass instance;
instance.add_buffer(first_buffer);
instance.add_buffer(second_buffer);
char* big_buffer = instance.read_all(); // big_buffer = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

**NOTE**: There are a lot of solutions for this problem but I'm looking for an efficient one because in real life the buffers will be many and big, and I want to save a lot of copying and reallocs (like what std::vector does). I'm also want a readble c++ code.

**NOTE**: The real life problem is: I'm reading data from an HTTP request that came to me at separated chunks. After all chunks arrived I want to return the whole data to the user.

Comment: Unless you've preallocated a ton of memory, you probably can't avoid several copying reallocs.

Comment: Yes I know. But I want to minimize it.

Comment: is it neasccery that the output buffer to have contiguous memory?

Comment: What `char first_buffer = [1,2,3];` is supposed to mean?

Comment: I'm reading data from an HTTP request that came to me at separated chunks. After all chunks arrived I want to return the whole data to the user.

Comment: ***So, what is your question?***  Questions usually end with Question Marks (**?**)

Comment: [`boost::algorithm::join`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1833499)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an `std::vector<char>` with enough memory [reserved](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve). Since C++11, you can access the internal buffer with [`std::vector::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) (until C++11, you have to use `&*std::vector::begin()`).

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Boost, `boost::algorithm::join` will do:

> ```
> #include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>
> #include <vector>
> #include <iostream>
>
> int main(int, char **)
> {
>     std::vector<std::string> list;
>     list.push_back("Hello");
>     list.push_back("World!");
>
>     std::string joined = boost::algorithm::join(list, ", ");
>     std::cout << joined << std::endl;
> }
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> Hello, World!
> ```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1833499/3821804) by Tristram Gräbener

Answer (score 0):

Use some standard approach like,

- start with some initial memory, say 256
- whenever it gets full use reallocate and double the size.

If you don't want to do it yourself, use STL containers like

```
std::vector<char>
```

It automatically reallocates memory for you when buffer is full.

Comment: Dangerous startegy if implemented exactly as written.

Comment: This is a pretty poor suggestion which will result in unacceptable and needless reallocations.

Comment: Even std::vector uses the same strategy.If anybody has any other strategy, please comment.