# How to concatenate strings with space into one string with STL in c++

Tags: c++, stl

Given a vector of string ["one", "two", "three"].

Question> How do I convert it into "one two three"?

I know the manual way to do it with a loop and would like to know whether
there is a simpler way with STL function.

// Updated based on suggestion that I should use `accumulate`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct BindTwoStrings
{
    string operator()(const string& s1, const string& s2) const {
        return s1.empty() ? s2 : s1 + " " + s2;
    }    
};

int main()
{    
   vector<string> vecString {"one", "two", "three"};   
   string ret2;   

   ret2 = accumulate(vecString.begin(), vecString.end(), ret2, 
           [] (const string& s1, const string& s2) -> string { 
              return s1.empty() ? s2 : s1 + " " + s2; });
   cout << "ret2:\"" << ret2 << "\"" << endl;

   string ret;
   ret = accumulate(vecString.begin(), vecString.end(), ret, BindTwoStrings());

   cout << "ret:\"" << ret << "\"" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or `std::stringstream` with `std::ostream_iterator` and `std::copy`.

Comment: [Concatenating strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720344/concatenating-strings)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `std::accumulate()`:

```
std::string concat = std::accumulate(std::begin(array) + 1, std::end(array), array[0],
    [](std::string s0, std::string const& s1) { return s0 += " " + s1; });
```

Comment: @P0W: that will have a leading space followed by a sequence of not separated strings...

Comment: @DietmarKühl, Ah, sorry, it didn't seem to give a space at the beginning for me, which I find odd now that I think about it.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Ahh yeah, accumulate always confuses me

Comment: @DietmarKühl, can you check my update post and see whether my solution work?

Comment: This works but slow as hell. std::ostringstream is much better in performance.

Answer (score 3):

With a `std::stringstream`, you could do that :

```
std::stringstream ss;
const int v_size = v.size();
for(size_t i = 0; i < v_size; ++i)  // v is your vector of string
{
  if(i != 0)
    ss << " ";
  ss << v[i];
}
std::string s = ss.str();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::ostream_iterator`.

```
std::vector< std::string > vs{ "one", "two", "three" };

std::ostringstream result_stream;
std::ostream_iterator< std::string > oit( result_stream, " " );
std::copy( vs.begin(), vs.end(), oit );

std::string result = result_stream.str();
```

http://ideone.com/VfxWbd

If you want the result in a string, use `std::ostringstream` for the output iterator.

Comment: Trailing space needs to be trimmed when `vs` is empty

Comment: @P0W How can you specify a requirement on someone else's question? Anyway just refer to the answer of the duplicate Q&A, which removes trailing space if the result is *not* empty.